# How to get the principle stretches of compressible Neo-Hookean material under uniaxial extension?

Tags: material-science, elasticity, non-linear-systems

As the title described, how the principal stretches of a compressible [Neo-Hookean material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Hookean_solid) undergoing uniaxial extension are derived from the constitutive model as below? 
$$
\lambda_1 = \lambda; \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = \sqrt \frac{J}{\lambda}
$$

Comment: Shouldn't there be a square root on the right hand side?

Comment: @ChetMiller. Yes, it should. I just corrected it.

Comment: Then what's the problem?

Comment: It looks like you have posted the answer, and are wanting to know how that equation was derived from first principles. A first step is to define the terms ($\lambda$ and $ J $) appearing in the formula. Doing so would also help others to understand the question and any answer.